# Запрос к серверу

Tags: http, get

По заданию, нужно сделать запрос на получение картинки img.jpg, размещенной на сервере http://www.test2.ru в папке images, при этом передать методом POST переменную tst=123. 
Запрос выглядит так

```
GET http://www.test2.ru/images/img.jpg HTTP/1.0\r\n  
Host: http://www.test2.ru\r\n  
Referer: http://www.test2.ru/index.html\r\n  
Cookie: income=1\r\n  
\r\n
```

Как при этом передать методом POST переменную tst=123 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
POST http://www.test2.ru/images/img.jpg HTTP/1.0\r\n  
Host: http://www.test2.ru\r\n  
Referer: http://www.test2.ru/index.html\r\n 
Cookie: income=1\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Content-Length: 7\r\n
\r\n
tst=123
```

content-length  - длина тела сообщения в байтах. tst=123 - 7 байт

Comment: вы уверены?

Comment: чуть поправил, добавил контент тайп и контент-лен. Так точнее будет.